# Cocoapods is not available, make sure it's installed and in your PATH

Tags: react-native, expo, cocoapods, eas

After execution `sudo eas build -p ios --profile production --local`
catching such a mistake

```
Cocoapods is not available, make sure it's installed and in your PATH
pod exited with non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`